# TypeError: unsipported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python

I am trying to modifying a python codes. Basically I made an GUI to rotate an object inside the model in one direction only (z axis). The code was written to handle vector. However, I need to use as orientation matrix. It is written like this:

```
def OrientationFromRxRyRzAngles(RxRyRzAnglesInRadians):
    S1, S2, S3 = map(sin, RxRyRzAnglesInRadians)
    C1, C2, C3 = map(cos, RxRyRzAnglesInRadians)
    return (
        (+C2 * C3, +C2 * S3, -S2),  # components in global axes directions, of unit vector in vessel x-axis direction
        # components in global axes directions, of unit vector in vessel y-axis direction
        (-C1 * S3 + S1 * S2 * C3, +C1 * C3 + S1 * S2 * S3, +S1 * C2),
        # components in global axes directions, of unit vector in vessel z-axis direction
        (+S1 * S3 + C1 * S2 * C3, -S1 * C3 + C1 * S2 * S3, +C1 * C2)
    )

class ExternallyCalculatedRotation(object):
    def Initialise(self, info):
        
        # Settings for outputting results to external output at a set period in seconds
        self.StartTime = 1
        self.TimeStep = info.Model['General'].ImplicitConstantTimeStep
        
        # Settings for outputting results to external output at a set period in seconds
        self.StartTime = 1
        self.TimeStep = info.Model['General'].ImplicitConstantTimeStep
        
        # Control object names in the model
        self.SupportMaster = "Constraint1"
        
        # Input to define the scale for the GUI. [Piston offset, Support offset, tension]
        self.GUItext = 'Support Offset (m)'
        self.ScaleMax = 100.0     # Scale maximum. Units: mm, m
        self.ScaleMin = 0           # Scale minimum. Units: mm, m
        self.RateMaxList = 0.30     # Maximum rate of cchange. Units: m/s. Note tension does not need to be gradually changed.
        self.ScaleRes = 0.01       # Slider scale resolution. Units: mm, m
       
        # Control settings for changing support offset
        if info.ModelObject.Name == self.SupportMaster:
            self.RateMax = self.RateMaxList                # m per second
            self.RateStep = self.RateMax * self.TimeStep        # m per time step
            self.maxOffset = self.ScaleMax                   # Defines the upper limit of the control slider scale
            self.TargetOffset = self.ScaleMin 
            self.TargetOffsetScale = 0
            info.Workspace['supportdata'] = self.TargetOffsetScale  # Workspace allows sharing of data between model objects

        # Define the PySimpleGUI slider
        # We only want to trigger the GUI once to create a single interface window. Workspace is used to share data between mode objects.
        if info.ModelObject.Name == self.SupportMaster:  
            gui.theme('DarkAmber') 
            layout = [
                [gui.Text(self.GUItext)],
                [gui.Slider(range=(self.ScaleMin, self.ScaleMax), default_value=self.ScaleMin, resolution=self.ScaleRes, size=(15, 15), orientation="v",
                            enable_events=True, key="support")]            
            ]
            self.window = gui.Window("slider GUI", layout)  
            
    def Calculate(self,info):
       
        # Only run for new time steps
        if not info.NewTimeStep:
            return
        
        # Read data from the control slider GUI. This will only be done for one model object, so we need to share values in workspace.
        if info.ModelObject.Name == self.SupportMaster:
            # Read data from the GUI slider if it is changed (an event). If no event after 0.01 seconds, then continue the code.
            event, values = self.window.Read(timeout=10)    
            # Exits the program if exit selected on the window
            if event in  (None, 'Exit'):
                sys.exit()       
            # Record the result if there is an input change.
            if event is not None:
                if event == "support":
                    info.Workspace['supportdata'] = values["support"]
                    
       
        # Define the target offset position and tension     
        if info.ModelObject.Name == self.SupportMaster:
            self.TargetOffsetScale = info.Workspace['supportdata']
            self.TargetOffset = self.TargetOffsetScale
            t = self.TargetOffset
        # Only start after the specified time
        if info.SimulationTime < self.StartTime:
            return
          
        # Rotational motion:
        EulerAnglesInRadians = (
                0,  # = Rx
                0,  # = Ry
                0 + 0.25 * (1.0 - cos(0.05 * t))  # = Rz
        )
        info.StructValue.Orientation = OrientationFromRxRyRzAngles(EulerAnglesInRadians)
       
                
        # Calculate the change in X-offset position 
        # Find the position error from the defined target position
        self.PositionLast = info.StructValue.Orientation[2]
        self.PositionError = self.PositionLast - t
        self.ErrorDir = numpy.sign(self.PositionError)
        # Get the position change required for the time step 
        if abs(self.PositionError) > self.RateStep:
            PositionNew = self.PositionLast - (self.RateStep * self.ErrorDir)
        else:
            if info.ModelObject.Name == self.SupportMaster:
                PositionNew = self.PositionLast 
            else: PositionNew = self.PositionLast - (self.PositionError * self.ErrorDir)

        # Return the X position to feed into the model
        info.StructValue.Orientation[2] = PositionNew              

    # Close the GUI window on reset                     
    def Finalise(self, info):
        self.window.close()
```

It gave some error line 104 in Calculate self.PositionError = self.PositionLast - t
TypeError: unsipported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

how to make that formula can handle a tuple? Please help me on this!

Thanks in advance!

Nubie

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subtract an int from the tuple you could do

`self.PositionError = tuple(map(lambda i, j: i - j, self.PositionLast, (t, t)))`

but probably cleaner, as this was adapted from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-get-subtraction-of-tuples/)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the code for `turtle.Vec2D` to build a `Vec3D` class.

Refer `turtle.Vec2D`, I have following code

```py
import math
from functools import cached_property

class Coordinate(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (x, y))

    @cached_property
    def x(self):
        return self[0]

    @cached_property
    def y(self):
        return self[1]

    @cached_property
    def distance(self):
        return math.dist(self, (0, 0))

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Coordinate):
            return Coordinate(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y)
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Coordinate(self.x+other, self.y+other)
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Coordinate):
            return Coordinate(self.x-other.x, self.y-other.y)
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Coordinate(self.x-other, self.y-other)
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Coordinate):
            return Coordinate(self.x*other.x, self.y*other.y)
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Coordinate(self.x*other, self.y*other)
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def __pos__(self):
        return self

    def __neg__(self):
        return Coordinate(-self.x, -self.y)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return -self.__sub__(other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.x}, {self.y})'

    def rotate(self, angle):
        angle = angle * math.pi / 180.0
        cos, sin = math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)
        return Coordinate(self.x*cos-self.y*sin, self.x*sin+self.y*cos)

a = Coordinate(3, 4)

print(a + 2)                # (5, 6)
print(a + a)                # (6, 8)
print(2 + a)                # (5, 6)
print(a - 2)                # (1, 2)
print(a - a)                # (0, 0)
print(2 - a)                # (-1, -2)
print(a * 2)                # (6, 8)
print(2 * a)                # (6, 8)
print(-a)                   # (-3, -4)
print(a.rotate(90))         # (-4.0, 3.0000000000000004)
print(a.x, a.y, a.distance) # 3 4 5.0
```